# Not able to get text of all options present in dropdown

Tags: selenium, dropdown, gettext

I am trying to get the text of all options present in the select language dropdown.

But I am not able to get them.

**Only "‪English (United Kingdom)" from all options in the dropdown is getting printed. Rest all languages are displayed as blank.**

Below is my code:

System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\1\chromedriver.exe");

```
    // Start browser
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    driver.get("https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin/identifier?elo=1&flowName=GlifWebSignIn&flowEntry=AddSession");

    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class = 'TquXA']")).click();

    List<WebElement> listOfLanguages = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//span[@class = 'vRMGwf oJeWuf']"));
    
    int size = listOfLanguages.size();
    
    for(int i = 0; i<size; i++) {
        
        WebElement ele = listOfLanguages.get(i);
        String value = ele.getText();
        System.out.println("languages are : "+value);
    }
    

    driver.quit();
```

Comment: I can't access the URL you put in driver.get, please give us a functional URL that's independent from your Google account so we can help you further!

Answer (score 0):

The language dropdown might not be immediately loaded by the time you retrieve the text. Try explicitwait conditions which makes sure all the dropdown elements are visible in DOM.

```
    WebDriverWait wait=new WebDriverWait(driver,20);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocated(By.xpath("//span[@class = 'vRMGwf oJeWuf']")));
```

If not visible in 20 seconds, the above code will throw TimeOutException.

Also, whenver printing text it is always good to use foreach loop for dynamic no.of elements.

The another option is to use sleep which sleeps for 3 seconds after the click. (Not a best approach, though it will work for you)
Eg: `Thread.sleep(3000);`

Comment: Hello Arun, As you guidance, I used a for-each loop now instead of regular and also used static Thread.sleep() wait for now. I see that if I put a wait of 5 seconds I am able to print approx 35-40 languages as compare to only 1 before. However, I am not able to print all the languages(71) in the output console even if I increase the sleep time to 15 seconds.

Comment: My updated code:Thread.sleep(15000);

  List<WebElement> listOfLanguages = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//span[@class = 'vRMGwf oJeWuf']"));

  int size = listOfLanguages.size();

  for (WebElement ele : listOfLanguages) {

   String value = ele.getText();
   System.out.println("languages are : " + value);
  }

  driver.quit();

Comment: @DeepakVishwakarma Pageload will be handled by selenium in default. Hence no need to set page load timeout unless you have a real usecase. Also, increase the implicitwait time to 30 seconds and check.